# GWT Maven and web.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, gwt, m2eclipse, web.xml

I'm using the GWT Maven plugin from Codehaus with m2eclipse. Where is my web.xml file supposed to end up? Isn't the Maven build supposed to copy it to the /war directory? I can't see it there. Or does Jetty pick it up automatically from src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/?

Here's a relevant section from my pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
  <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
  <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe web.xml (and everything else under `src/main/webapp/`) gets copied into `target/<projectname>-<version>/` during the normal maven lifecycle (For example, when you run `mvn install`).

If you're running any of the gwt-maven plugin goals, then check out [this link](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/war-folder.html).

When running gwt:run, if you want to run the full web app just as if you have built and deployed a war, I found the best way is to add the following to the configuration for the gwt-maven plugin:

```
<hostedWebapp>
            ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}
</hostedWebapp>
```

This tells gwt-maven plugin to look for the web.xml (and all the other parts of the war file) under `target/<projectname>-<version>/`. So make sure to either run `mvn install` first (or `mvn war:exploded`), then run `mvn gwt:run` and you should be set.